# How can I trigger a contact workflow on a specific date in Bitrix24?

Tags: triggers, workflow, bitrix

I would like to trigger a workflow resetting a sum on all contacts every 1st January of the year. The workflow is implemented. It could be triggered on the specific date or even everyday, because the date is verified in the workflow before resetting.
How can i run it on every contact?

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow, the answer to your question is as the following:

1. You need to create a Rest API outbound webhook in your Bitrix account with "CRM" & "Business Process" permissions.
2. You will write down a PHP code that will be executed on the exact date/time of you choice
3. The PHP script will do 2 process:
4. Will retrieve all the contacts that you have on your Bitrix account and store them into a string value.
5. It will run that Business process and pass the list of all the found contacts, and inside your Business process you're going to set it up in a way that it will run the required actions on every contact from eh contacts IDs passed by the first step.

The PHP script can be hosted in a webhosting or even on your local machine since it's once a year.

This is only the concept of the solution, I can't share the script code because I don't have it at the moments, please contact me if you faces problems.